# RecyclerView Adapter not updating in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I've been messing around with RecyclerView, and I've got it working properly and correctly in Activity; but as soon as I try it in a Fragment, it just won't update the UI.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddItemDialog.OnItemAddedListener {

    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    private FragmentManager manager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerFragment rvf = new RecyclerFragment();
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.frag_container, rvf, "TAG");
        ft.commit();

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            AddItemDialog dialog = new AddItemDialog();
                dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DIALOG");
            }
        });
        fab.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), _3DTouch.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(String entry) {
        RecyclerFragment rvfFrag = (RecyclerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG");
        rvfFrag.refreshData(entry);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick() {}
}
```

FragmentAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jfelt on 15/04/2016.
 */
public class FragmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FragmentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<TestEntry> testEntries = Collections.emptyList();

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return testEntries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup vg, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(vg.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.entry, vg, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder vh, int i) {
        vh.textView.setText(testEntries.get(i).getItem());
    }
}
```

RecyclerFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.UiThread;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jfelt on 14/04/2016.
 */
public class RecyclerFragment extends Fragment {

    List<TestEntry> testEntries = new ArrayList<>();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;

    public RecyclerFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            Log.d("RecyclerFragment", String.valueOf(args));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        adapter = new FragmentAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup vg, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rv = inf.inflate(R.layout.rv_layout, null);
        return rv;
    }

    public void refreshData(String entry) {
        Log.d("TAG", entry);
        testEntries.add(new TestEntry(entry));
        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(testEntries));
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyItemInserted(testEntries.size() - 1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logging shows that refreshData receives the input from the Dialog listener. The issue appears to be in calling adapter.notifyItemInserted, in that it doesn't seem to be called properly. I've probably missed something blatantly obvious but I've been staring at this code for hours and just can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how do you refer testEntries inside Fragment to the testEntries inside Adapter? I think the problem is you dont tell you adapter updated data. I recommend make a function inside Adapter to add the entries to it and then notifyItemsInserted.

Inside FragmentAdapter:

```
public void addItem(String entry){
    this.testEntries.add(entry);
    notifyItemInserted(testEntries.size() - 1);
}
```

Inside Fragment:

```
((FragmentAdapter) getAdapter()).addItem(entry);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FragmentAdapter` and `RecyclerFragment` our referencing different lists so when you add an item to one it doesn't get added to the other.

One option that will work with your current code structure is to add a constructor to `FragmentAdapter` that takes a `List` so that they both have the same `List` reference:

```
public FragmentAdapter(List<TestEntry testEntries) {
    this.testEntries = testEntries;
}
```

and then in `onViewCreated()` of your fragment pass in its list as a parameter to the `FragmentAdapter` constructor.

```
adapter = new FragmentAdapter(testEntries);
```

Also you do not need `getActivity().runOnUiThread` since you are already on the UI thread at that point. You can just make the calls to add the item.

```
testEntries.add(new TestEntry(entry));
adapter.notifyItemInserted(testEntries.size() - 1);
```